# Unable to run java annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, javac, processor

I am having troubles running my annotation processor from command line. 
The problem is that it works in Windows environment, but not on my linux installation.

My processor is located in a jar file (meta-validator.jar). I also added entry to META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor containing fully qualified name of class of my processor.

I am trying to invoke annotation processor with this command:

```
javac -cp "./metadata-validator.jar; ... (path to annotations.jar etc.)" -processor xammt.validator.modules.ValidatorModule -proc:only " ... path to sources"
```

In Windows environment it just works (Windows 7 64bit Pro, JDK 1.7.xx), processor is found and process method is executed.

In my linux environment (Linux Mint 13 32bit -> basically Ubuntu 12.04, Oracle JDK 1.7) I get message:

```
error: Annotation processor 'xammt.validator.modules.ValidatorModule' not found
warning: Annotation processing without compilation requested but no processors were found.
```

Also without `-processor` switch I get the same warning (with other verbose stuff).

What could be causing this problem? I guess that my JDK on linux machine is installed correctly, because I am able to run/compile java applications without any problems.

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:** I have still no idea why this does not work. Funny thing is, that it works programmatically - I managed to invoke my annotation processor via Java Compiler API without problems (on both platforms), this is also better solution because of debugging.

**EDIT2:** 
Actual command:

```
javac -cp "./metadata-validator.jar;./lib/common-library.jar;./Annotation source.jar" 
-processor xammt.validator.modules.ValidatorModule -proc:only "SourceFile.java"
```

**SOLVED:**
check [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)#OS_specific_notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#OS_specific_notes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux are you using colon instead of semicolon as your class path separator?  Include the Linux command you are executing as well.

Change the semi-colons to colons in the classpath and it should work.

Like this:

```
javac -cp "./metadata-validator.jar:./lib/common-library.jar:./Annotation source.jar" -processor xammt.validator.modules.ValidatorModule -proc:only "SourceFile.java"
```

Comment: Unless the problem is in fact the use of the wrong path separator.  If so, then that's the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea.

Comment: you just saved my life

Answer (score 1):

I also found out that the version of OpenJDK 7 included in Debian Wheezy (7u3) simply does not work with annotation processors. I did a custom build of OpenJDK 7u9 (from Ubuntu Quantal) and it works perfectly.

I reported a bug in Debian's bugtracker: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=697658